# Why different behavior between arguments object and arguments like object?

Tags: javascript

When I passed object like arguments' object I receive an empty array. Why?

```js
function checkArguments() {
    console.log(arguments)//[Arguments] { '0': 'first', '1': 'second' }
    console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))//[ 'first', 'second' ]
    console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call({'0': 'first','1': 'second'}))// [] ? why empty array    
}
  
checkArguments("first", "second")
```

Comment: you miss the `length` property.

Comment: btw, it is an *array like object*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work similarly to how arguments behaves, you'd need to explicitly define a length property on your object:

```
console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call( {'0': 'first','1': 'second',length:2}))
```

Answer (score 0):

The **Array.prototype.slice.call** method is expecting an array-like object, meaning an object with a numerical **length** property and indexed elements starting from 0.

In your example:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call({'0': 'first','1': 'second'})
```

The object **{'0': 'first', '1': 'second'}** doesn't have a **length** property and isn't recognized as an array-like object. That's why you get an empty array.

To convert your custom object to an array, you can use **Object.values**:

```
console.log(Array.from(Object.values({'0': 'first', '1': 'second'})));
```

This will give you the desired result ['first', 'second'].

Comment: *"indexed elements starting from 0"* no. the length is important and values at indices outside of the length are ignored.